# Let $\{H_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an indexed family of subgroups containing a normal subgroup $N$. Is $(\bigcap_{i \in I} H)/N = \bigcap_{i \in I} H_i/N$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $\{H_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an indexed family of subgroups containing a normal subgroup $N$. Does the equality $(\bigcap_{i \in I} H_i)/N = \bigcap_{i \in I} H_i/N$ hold?

I'm starting off by assuming that if $\overline{x} \in \bigcap_{i \in I} H_i/N$ then for all $i \in I$, there exists $h_i \in H_i$ such that $\overline{x} = h_i N$. To prove that $\overline{x}$ is in $(\bigcap_{i \in I} H_i)/N$, I would need to prove that $\overline{x}$ equals some $hN$ such that $h \in \bigcap_{i \in I} H_i$. However, I'm not sure how to prove that the former implies the latter representative exists, and I'm not sure how to come up with a counterexample either.

The other subset inclusion is trivial (if $\overline{x} \in (\bigcap_{i \in I}H_i)/N)$, then $\overline{x} = hN$ for $h \in H_i$ for all $i \in I$, so $\overline{x} \in H_i/N$ for all $i \in I$).

Thank you in advance for your input!

Edit: Ahh, I feel like an idiot.

Take arbitrary $h_j N = h_i N$ Since $N$ is a subgroup of $H_i$, then $h_j$ is equal to $h_i n$ which is also in $H_i$. Therefore, any arbitrary $h_j$ representative is in the intersection of all the $H_i$.

Comment: Please don't answer a post by editing the post. Write an actual answer, and leave put the meta commentary.

Comment: Regarding feeling like an idiot, [you're in good company](https://youtu.be/Uxa1gLt5YKI).

Answer (score 1):

Take arbitrary $h_jN=h_iN$ Since $N$ is a subgroup of $H_i$, then $h_j$ is equal to $h_in$ which is also in $H_i$. Therefore, any arbitrary $h_j$ representative is in the intersection of all the $H_i$.

I feel like this should have been obvious to me as I knew of the Lattice Isomorphism theorem and while I didn't know the proof, I could have very easily looked that up and generalized it to an arbitrary collection of sets. Please let me know if this post should be deleted.